# GHC: how to build a 32-bit DLL using 64-bit GHC? (To call functions from c++)

Tags: haskell, dll, ghc

I'd like to build the 32-bit DLL with 64-bit GHC. And here is the minimal example.

**Test.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Test where

import Foreign.C.Types

foreign export ccall c_hello :: IO()
foreign export ccall boo :: CInt

c_hello :: IO()
c_hello = do
    print "Hello!"
```

**init_exit.cpp**

```
#include "Test_stub.h"
#include <C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\lib\include\Rts.h>

#define DLLExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLExport void hello()
{
    c_hello();    
}

DLLExport int HsStart()
{
    int argc = 1;
    char* argv[] = {"ghcDLL", NULL};

    char** args = argv;
    hs_init(&argc, &args);

    printf("Haskell library has been initialized!\n");
    return 0;
}

DLLExport int HsEnd()
{
    hs_exit();

    printf("Haskell library has been finalized!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And then I build the library, using the following commands:

```sh
ghc -c -O Test.hs 
ghc -c init_exit.cpp 
ghc -shared -o Test.dll Test.o init_exit.o
```

What flags should I pass to ghc or maybe to gcc to build the 32-bit DLL instead of 64-bit? Or maybe there is another way to do this.

Comment: perhaps this link: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Compiling32on64 will help?

Comment: @TomaszLewowski Blame on me, I forget to specify that I have Windows on this particular machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal Windows 64-bit GHC build (such as the one you can download from the GHC website) is only capable of building 64-bit object files. For example, it doesn't include 32-bit versions of any of the libraries that come with GHC.

Your options are to build a Windows 64-bit to Windows 32-bit cross-compiler, or just run the normal Windows 32-bit build of GHC (probably much easier).